# iOS Swift - UISlider - Add a second track bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uislider

I'm trying to customize my subclassed UISlider to add a second track bar underneath the draggable thumb. The idea here is to have this new track represent the "average rating" and the existing thumb and track being used by users to set their own rating. I tried inserting a custom layer but it either sits behind the entire slider or on top of the entire slider including the draggable thumb. Any help/insight on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's an image of what I am trying to achieve. The blue bar I'd like to be this added track that represents the "average rating":

[image]

Comment: Instead of munging UISlider, build your own UIControl from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `addSublayer()`, try using [insertSublayer(_: at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410944-insertsublayer). This would give you full control of where exactly in the layers hierarchy you want to insert your `average rating layer` instance.

---

#### UPDATE

Try inspecting the `self.layer.sublayers` for your `UISlider` instance. If you can easily identify the `thumbLayer` (say based on `bounds.size` or anything unique to it). Then you could attempt inserting your  layer

1. below thumb using [insertSublayer(_: below:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410840-insertsublayer)
2. above progress track (in case you can identify it) using [insertSublayer(_: above:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410798-insertsublayer)

Comment: I actually am using insertSublayer (after checking). If i insert at 0 it puts it behind the entier slider and if i insert at 1 it puts it front of the entire slider (including the tracking thumb). I think this is because the entire UISlider is represented as a single layer

Comment: See the UPDATE for another possible workaround.

Comment: Checked that as well - I only see a single sublayer :/

Comment: If you inspect this in the `View Hierarchy Debugger`, how many subviews does a `UISlider` have?